# Failed to use DDMS to push file with unicode filename to Android emulator, any solution?

Tags: android, ddms

The filename of my file contains unicode character. When I tried to push it to the Android emulator by DDMS, it failed and thrown the invalid argument error.

I searched the Internet, some people said that DDMS only accepts ASCII filename. Is it correct ?

Is there any solution to overcome this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to push file from command line?

```
adb push foo.txt /sdcard/foo.txt
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html